# Adding an attribute in the root of a lot of SVG files

Tags: python, ubuntu, svg, sed, terminal

I have a folder of svg files, call it svg.

The first line for each of them, looks something like:

```
<ns0:svg xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="296.90mm" version="1.2" viewBox="0 0 118.6170 167.6220" width="210.10mm">
```

I want to change it to:

```
<ns0:svg xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="296.90mm" version="1.2" viewBox="0 0 118.6170 167.6220" width="210.10mm" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
```

So, the entire point is to add shape-rendering="crispEdges" to each of the files. However, I have a lot of these files (hundreds of thousands), so I need it to be as efficient as possible.

Does anyone know a quick way of doing so, be it from python or from Ubuntu terminal?

Thanks!

Comment: you'll have to show your own efforts to solve it... easy enough with `sed`.. you can specify that you need to change only 1st line, use regex to replace `>` at end of line with desired string, use `-i` option to perform inplace editing and so on... see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info

Comment: I haven't used these tools before. I can do it on Python, but it doesn't look efficient to me.

Comment: then add the Python code here.. if there are issues, am sure you'll get help here... if it works well but you want to know areas of improvement, ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ... `haven't used these tools before` then you'll have to start learning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably sed is a best tool for your purpose.

```
sed -e -i 's/<ns0:svg\(.*\)>/<ns0:svg\1 shape-rendering="crispEdges" >/g' <files_you_want_to_update>
```

Comment: This seems to not work to me. It doesn't recognize the -e command, and without it it says no input files (despite that I am in the folder where there are svg files).

Comment: @TheRevanchist updated an answer, you need to specify files you want to update.

Comment: Cool, I changed your code to iterate over the files and it is working like a charm. I am putting the solution in the OP (because here it doesn't look nice with the formatting), and accepting your answer.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with awk then you could try following also.

```
awk -v s1="shape-rendering=\"crispEdges\"" '{sub(/>$/,FS s1 ">")} 1'   Input_file > temp_file  && mv temp_file  Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** Adding a non-one liner form of solution with explanation too here.

```
awk -v s1="shape-rendering=\"crispEdges\"" '{                      ##creating variable named s1 which will have value of string mentioned by OP.
                                                sub(/>$/,FS s1 ">")##substituting last occurrence with FS s1 > with it in the line.
                                            }
                                            1                      ##Writing 1 means making the condition TRUE and NOT mentioning any action here so by default print of current line will happen.
                                           ' Input_file > temp_file \ ## Writing output of this into a temp_file then continuing the following command.
                                           && mv  temp_file  Input_file## && means if previous commands is SUCCESSFUL then rename temp_file to Input_file
```

***EDIT2:*** As per OP's request I am changing my code according to .svg files and it will save individual Input_file itself with changes(if any).

```
awk -v temp_file="file" -v s1="shape-rendering=\"crispEdges\"" 'FNR==1 && f{
                                                    ####print "f= "f,"filename= " FILENAME
                                                    close(temp_file);
                                                    close(f);
                                                    system("mv "temp_file FS f);
                                                    f=""
                                                   }
                                        /ns0:svg xmlns:ns0=\"w3.org\/2000\/svg\"/
                                        {
                                            sub(/>$/,FS s1 ">")
                                        }
                                        {if(!f)
                                        {
                                            f=FILENAME
                                        }}
                                        {
                                            print > temp_file;
                                        }
                                       '  *.svg
```

Comment: How can I do this for an entire folder with svg files? Sorry, I haven't ever used these tools, and I do not know if you can iterate over files with them.

Comment: I could edit my post if you want to do this for specific files, my question will be to you do you want to save the changes into the Input_file itself? Kindly do let me know on same.

Comment: Yes, I want the changes to be saved in the input files. So, in the end of the process, there should be the same files, but each of them should have that extra attribute.

Comment: @TheRevanchist: I had changed my code see in EDIT2 now and let me know if this helps you. Also please try with a test 1 or 2 files once you are satisfied then you could go for real requirement, let me know how it goes then, cheers.

Comment: There is something wrong with your code. It adds shape-rendering = crispEdges everywhere, not only in the first line.

Looks something like:

<ns0:svg xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="296.90mm" version="1.2" viewBox="0 0 118.6170 167.6220" width="210.10mm" shape-rendering="crispEdges">

<ns0:text fill="currentColor" font-family="serif" font-size="2.2004" text-anchor="start" transform="translate(5.6457, 7.3056)" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
<ns0:tspan shape-rendering="crispEdges">
...

Only on the first line the attribute should be added.

Comment: see my edit now, so my code will look for sting (ns0:svg xmlns:ns0="w3.org/2000/svg") in a line, if you have any other text to look you could try changing it with your desired one then, careful with escaping the characters here like I changed " to \" etc else they will be showing their special meaning on it, let me know how it goes then.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it isn't working. It is adding crispEdges all over the file, not only in the first line. Regardless, I found the solution using sed, by slightly modifying A. Haaji's answer.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Thanks to A. Haaji's reply, the problem is solved. I just had to iterate over a list of files, and then using their code, everything works. The final solution is:

```
for i in *.svg
do
    sed -i 's/<ns0:svg\(.*\)>/<ns0:svg\1 shape-rendering="crispEdges" >/g' "$i"
done
```